# Remove all Timer Objects from Movie AS3 Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, timer

I am adding a Timer object when my flv playback enters a Pause state and removing that Timer Object when playback starts again. I noticed that if I pause the movie and then drag the slider on the timeline the movie enters the Pause State again which adds another Timer Object....

My question: How do I check to see if the Timer has already been added and if so remove it and add a new one.

See code below:

```
    my_player.addEventListener(VideoEvent.PAUSED_STATE_ENTERED, pausePlay);
    my_player.addEventListener(VideoEvent.PLAYING_STATE_ENTERED, startPlay);

function pausePlay(e:VideoEvent):void {

     //HERE IS WERE I NEED TO REMVOVE ALL completeTimer's BEFORE ADDING ANOTHER ONE.
        completeTimer = new Timer(pause_timeout,1);
        completeTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, completeListener);
        completeTimer.start();
        trace ("IN THE PAUSE LISTENER");
}

function startPlay(e:VideoEvent):void {
    completeTimer.reset();


}
```

Comment: have you tried using the hasEventListener() method?

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking that you could do something like this..

```
//CREATE A SINGLE TIMER..
var completeTimer = new Timer(pause_timeout,1);
completeTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, completeListener);

function pausePlay(e:VideoEvent):void {
    completeTimer.start();
    trace ("IN THE PAUSE LISTENER");
}
function startPlay(e:VideoEvent):void {
    completeTimer.reset();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think the intention would be to actually store the original pause time still and not create a new timer no?

```
my_player.addEventListener(VideoEvent.PAUSED_STATE_ENTERED, pausePlay);
my_player.addEventListener(VideoEvent.PLAYING_STATE_ENTERED, startPlay);

function pausePlay(e:VideoEvent):void {

     //HERE IS WERE I NEED TO REMVOVE ALL completeTimer's BEFORE ADDING ANOTHER ONE.
        if(!completeTimer)
        {
                completeTimer = new Timer(pause_timeout,1);
                completeTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, completeListener);
                completeTimer.start();
                trace ("IN THE PAUSE LISTENER");
        }
}

function startPlay(e:VideoEvent):void {
    completeTimer.reset();
    completeTimer = null;
}
```

Also you probably want to use TimerEvent.COMPLETE although it'll be the same in this case since there is only one tick of the timer, the event you're listening on would fire during every tick rather than after the number of ticks specified has been run.  (also note you're delay is in milliseconds not seconds so this would fire 1000 times per second or once after 1/1000th of a second).